# OpenERP POS - javascript get field added to orderline

Tags: odoo

Here is what I did in python:

```
class pos_order_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "pos.order.line"
    _columns = {
        'order_line_state_id': fields.many2one('pos.order.line.state', "Order Line State"),
    }

class pos_order_line_state(osv.osv):
    _name = "pos.order.line.state"

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name', size=18),
        'sequence': fields.integer('Sequence'),
    }
```

And in javascript I do:

```
var order = this.pos.get('selectedOrder');    
var line = order.getSelectedLine();
```

But **line** doesn't have **order_line_state_id** even though the column is in the database (checked with PGadminIII)

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.pos` is a reference to the original unmodified PosModel, not the one you have inherited. That's why you have the `order_line_state_id` in the database but it's not a member variable of the JS object.

I don't yet have any experience on JavaScript hacking in OpenERP so I don't know how to solve this. You might want to browse the JS code of the `point_of_sale` module and make the PosModel use your custom module instead of the original one.